# How to run a procedure in a package body

Tags: oracle, package, procedure

I am using oracle 11g . I am trying to run a procedure inside a package by using the command

```
execute package.procedure
```

but I keep getting the exception

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 12:
PLS-00302: component 'package' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

The package and package body i created is the following. What i am actually trying to do here is to create a package which is used to create tables each time its executed. so i wrote the following script.

-----Package

```
create or replace package pack1 as
end pack1 ;
/
```

------Package Body

```
create or replace package body pack1 as
procedure proc1
is 
begin
execute immediate 'create table bcd(bc date)';
end ;
procedure proc2
is 
begin
execute immediate 'create table bcde(bc number(12,0)) as select country_id from      countries';
end ;
end pack1;
/
```

but when i ran

```
execute pack1.proc2 ;
```

It gave me the above exception.

Can someone help me with what is wrong ?

Thanks a ton in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Procedures and functions in a package are private by default. [To make them public you have to declare them in the package specification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/packages.htm#i2412):

```
create or replace package pack1 as
procedure proc1;
procedure proc2;
end pack1;
/
```

Creating tables on the fly doesn't sounds like a good idea though.

Comment: so if creating tables in a package is not good , what else should i be doing ? My use case is such that i need to create these tables populate values from a remote db , once this copying data is successful i need move these values to a different table in production environment .. and drop the temp tables.

Comment: @rakesh - How often are you doing it, and always with the same tables? You might want to look at [global temporary tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10595/tables003.htm#i1006400), which persist data within a session. You'd create the GTT once and reuse it many times. If that doesn't sound suitable it might be a good separate question.

Comment: the basic plan is to use dbms scheduler to run these procedures every two hours.

Comment: @rakesh - from your brief outline I think GTT ought to be suitable for this, but you'll need to read up on it to see if it matches all your needs.